# Adapt standard "Comment as answer" template

Tags: discussion, comments

I've found a few answers with the following comment:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post
>   - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

My objection to this formulation is when it is used towards posters with low reputation and they were not the author of the question.

- First the poster is told that they should do something they can't yet do
- Second explains that you can comment in other specific situations which was not relevant where the comment is used
- The last part is OK

**Update:** Removed suggestion

After reading [James answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280187/33236) I realize that the problem I saw is not formulation itself but rather its presentation.

I do agree with James as far as documentation or general information goes.

When I first read the comment above on an answer I though that this commenter had neglected the fact that the person posting as an answer was unable to comment because of rep. Had it been a link or a quoted text it would have been clearer that you are given general information rather than someone commenting without reading your situation.

As a long time but not frequent user of SO I was unable to differentiate a template from a well formulated text.

Comment: It's the same template text used for low and higher rep users.

Answer (score 3):

I think that comment is fine for educating users on the way the site works, and that answers are not a substitute for comments. And caters for all similar scenarios without the need for having different comments.

The full comment broken down:

**THE PROBLEM:**
"This does not provide an answer to the question."
**WHAT YOU SHOULD DO INSTEAD:**
"To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post"
**HOW TO COMMENT:**
"you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post."

I think that's logical, informative, and useful, and if they don't understand from that, then there's Meta and the Help Centre.
The info is there to be found without much effort, and if they are not willing to help themselves, then it makes no difference what that message states.

---

> My objection to this formulation is when it is used towards posters
>   with low reputation

You are trying to help new users who don't have knowledge of the site etc, but your suggested resolve removes such important information that is useful especially to new users:

> <strike>To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a
>   comment below their post - you can always comment on your own
>   posts,</strike>

Why negate to tell *new users* how to request info, why they shouldn't have used the answer function here, and that they can comment on their own posts without rep?

---

> First the poster is told that they should do something they can't yet
>   do

Well, yes, but the same issue can be found if you break up any description or information. One does have to read the full paragraph, as is the same with a lot of information on systems, procedures, etc.

> Second explains that you can comment in other specific situations
>   which was not relevant where the comment is used

Arguably it's not relevant to this scenario, however why not give the user a comprehensive description of where they *can* and *can't* comment?

Only providing "You need rep to comment on other's posts" is not a full description, and they might not know they don't require rep to comment on their own posts.

> My suggestion is that a special version of this comment is used when
>   1. The poster does not have the reputation to comment
>   2. The poster is not the author of the question

The comment you are wanting to change already caters for your points 1 and 2.

Comment: Talking about documentation I agree with you.
Does it change anything that it was presented as a comment?